# Is the set of rational numbers $\frac{a}{b}$ such that $b \mid (a^2d+1)$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Fix some integer $d \geq 1$ for the problem. I'm hoping to show that the set of rational numbers of the form $a/b$ where $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $b$ divides $a^2d + 1$ is still dense in the real line.

For motivation, this problem is actually closely tied to showing certain vector bundles on a degree $d$ polarized K3 surface exist — unfortunately my number theory is lacking. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I edited the question since I'm pretty sure John's assumptions are correct, but OP make sure the question is correct when you see this. ($d$ is surely an integer since it is the degree of a bundle)

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for pointing that out and correcting; yes that was supposed to say $a^2 d + 1$, and yes $d \geq 1$ is supposed to be an integer.